# How to get the terminal leaves of a Wikipedia root category

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to get only the leaves a wikipedia category but not sure how. I can get all the leaves by

```
SELECT ?subcat WHERE  {
?subcat  skos:broader* category:Buildings_and_structures_in_France_by_city .
}
```

This gives me all intermediate leaves (such as Category:Buildings_and_structures_in_Antibes) but I want to get just the last/bottom leaves of the tree. Leaves that can not be split anymore.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *should* be able to simply filter out the values of `?subcat` that are not terminal leaves:

```
select ?subcat where  {
  ?subcat skos:broader* category:Buildings_and_structures_in_France_by_city .
  filter not exists { [] skos:broader ?subcat }
}
```

However, when I run that, I get no results.  I'm not sure why. I'd guess that it's one of the idiosyncrasies of Virtuoso (the SPARQL endpoint on DBpedia), but I'm not sure.  However, we can write an equivalent query that counts the number of things that each **?subcat** is **skos:broader** than, and selects only those that are **skos:broader** than none:

```
select distinct ?subcat where {
  ?subcat  skos:broader* category:Buildings_and_structures_in_France_by_city .
  optional { ?subsubcat skos:broader ?subcat }
} 
group by ?subcat
having count(?subsubcat) = 0
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fsubcat%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fsubcat%20%20skos%3Abroader*%20category%3ABuildings_and_structures_in_France_by_city%20.%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fsubsubcat%20skos%3Abroader%20%3Fsubcat%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0Agroup%20by%20%3Fsubcat%0D%0Ahaving%20count%28%3Fsubsubcat%29%20%3D%200&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)