# SPARQL query returns no results when a property path is present

Tags: sparql

The following query returns some results which have skos:broader set as category:History

```
select ?subject
where 
{
      ?subject skos:broader category:History .
}
```

However replacing `skos:broader` with `skos:broader+` or `skos:broader*` returns no results. Why is this? I would expect ethier to fetch at least the results returned in the first query.

I'm using the SPARQL front end here: http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: Virtuoso (the endpoint DBpedia is running) doesn't support all of SPARQL 1.1, I think, and this might be one of those edge cases.  Something very similar came up with property paths and skos:broader in a recent question, [How to get the terminal leaves of a Wikipedia root category](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26367211/1281433).  I'm not sure whether the solution there will help much in this case, though.

Comment: As an example of the awkward handling of property paths, DBpedia chokes on the query `ask { category:History skos:broader* category:History }` with the message "Virtuoso 42000 Error TN...: Exceeded 1000000000 bytes in transitive temp memory.  use t_distinct, t_max or more T_MAX_memory options to limit the search or increase the pool"  It ought to be able to trivially answer `true`, since `...*` matches a path of length 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtuoso (the endpoint that DBpedia uses) has some idiosyncrasies, supports some non-standard syntax (which often leads people to wonder why a query that worked on DBpedia doesn't work with other libraries), and (I think) doesn't support *all* of SPARQL 1.1.  This may be a case where you've run into some internal limitations.  You can approximate the results that you want with a query like the following, though:

```
select ?category { ?category skos:broader{,7} category:History }
```

This only follows paths of length seven or less. The {m,n} notation for property paths isn't part of SPARQL 1.1, but was in early drafts, and Virtuoso supports it.  It *is* convenient for limiting the resources used in answer a query, and this is a good use case for it.